# Web Scraping on a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape the table on this [link](https://steria.taleo.net/careersection/in_cs_ext_fs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&radiusType=K&location=462170431401&searchExpanded=true&radius=1). I was trying to use selenium to get the data after the page loaded but I was unsuccessful. Any other ideas on how I can scrape the table from that webpage?

EDIT -

I tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://steria.taleo.net/careersection/in_cs_ext_fs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&radiusType=K&location=462170431401&searchExpanded=true&radius=1") 
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('table').text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: the problem is you are not passing any search criteria, untill you pass keyword and then click search button, the result will not come, after that you can get the table

Comment: @Exprator so should i use selenium to click that search button and then see the results? But in my browser i dont click any button the results get loaded after a while

Comment: if i go to the link you have i see no results, that means we need to provide some search criteria to fetch the results, so you can use selenium to pass the data and then get the result

Comment: you can use  @Andersson's answer, it will work, as now i saw the link loads the results after few time

Comment: @Exprator thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As table content generated dynamically, you should wait until `JavaScript` executed to be able to get required data:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://steria.taleo.net/careersection/in_cs_ext_fs/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&radiusType=K&location=462170431401&searchExpanded=true&radius=1")
table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//table[@id='jobs' and ./tbody/tr]")))
print(table.text)
next_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
next_button.click()

wait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: next_button.get_attribute("aria-disabled") == "true")
table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//table[@id='jobs' and ./tbody/tr]")))
print(table.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: How would I be able to parse and save the second page of table also?

Comment: In exactly the same way: just put `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()` before `table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//table[@id='jobs' and ./tbody/tr]")))`

Comment: The same page gets parsed again and printed, cant print the second page

Comment: It seem to be issue with `Next` button. The easiest solution will be to add simple `time.sleep(1)` after `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()`

Comment: Yes some weird next button, was trying `driver.find_element_by_id('next').click()` but it gives me a TimeoutException: Message: ''

Comment: Still getting a timeout. Any other way to do it?

Comment: `---> 8 table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//table[@id='jobs' and ./tbody/tr]")))`

Comment: Works, but can you explain why that timeout was happening?

Comment: You probably incorrectly implemented that string as both current (with `wait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: next_button.get_attribute("aria-disabled") == "true")`) and previous (with `time.sleep(1)`) code works well from my side...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Beautiful Soup, look at this article: http://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/

Comment: The page is loaded after javascript runs. Its not embedded in it.